# Handle any type in method

Tags: c#, delegates, types

I have two classes.

```
public class Handler
{

delegate T ReturnDelegate();

    public T HandleReturnMethod(ReturnDelegate d)
    {
        DoSomething(); //some other stuff

        return d();
    }
} 


public partial class Test
{

    protected int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return new Handler().HandleReturnMethod(delegate()
            {
                int id = 1;
                return id; 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to handle any Type in the Handler class. But 'T' seems not to work, int cannot be converted to it.
If there is a better approach or something is wrong here, please comment.

Comment: Command pattern? Not sure, but have a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the delegate type and method to use generics.  Personally, I would use a standard delegate for this:

```
public T HandleReturnMethod<T>(Func<T> d)
{
    DoSomething(); //some other stuff
    return d();
}
```

Given the above, your code should work:

```
protected int Id
{
    get
    {
        return new Handler().HandleReturnMethod(() =>
        {
            int id = 1;
            return id; 
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code wasn't working is because **int** ( **Int32** ) is a structure not an object which is the reason it cannot normally be nullable
unless you declare it as **int? num = null;**

If I am not mistaken only an **object** can have a **Type** ( both an object and a Type are classes ) not a structure.  All classes are based on the object class ( which is the reason a collection that isn't a generic ( i.e. Type t ) elements are objects.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx